# Updating QGIS from 2.8.1 Wien to 3.12.2

Tags: qgis, update

I am relatively inexperienced in using GIS systems, but was able to make great use of QGIS several years ago to make distribution maps for my dissertation. I'd like to keep QGIS updated. What will happen if I update from 2.8.1 to 3.12.2? I seem to recall updating it in the past and having to put quite a lot of things right manually before I could use it again. Would it be a more straightforward process this time?

Comment: updating is usually easy but the exact procedure may differ between operating system, if you could tell us witch OS you use and what problem you encounter last time you'll get more answer.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to GIS StackExchange.

I believe that from 2.8 to 3.12 was a several upgrades in the code that has corrected some kind of erros/bugs and the instalation/setting is it a little bit more easy than was. Of course, if you'll use your old project from 2.8 you'll have to do some modifications.
Here is two links that can help you in instalation, the first one is the official site of QGIS, and the second it's a tutorial, may help you too. Otherwise in the youtube have a bunch of videos and tutorials that certainly may help you just as it helped me.

QGIS.org
[QGIS Installers](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html?highlight=install)

AWF-Wiki
[QGIS Instalation](http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/QGIS_installation#Installation_Guide_for_Mac_OS)

Answer (score 0):

QGIS 2 to 3 is a big jump.

I would keep 2.8.1, and install 3.12.2 alongside it. Then you can see what needs updating.

But if it is a simple project, you might not have to change anything.